# Spring REST API register date converter for pojo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-request-parameters, path-variables

Spring rest provides building pojo functionality by default from path variables and url parameters.

In my case I have pojo:

```
public class MyCriteria {
  private String from;
  private String till;
  private Long communityNumber;
  private String communityName;
}
```

that is used in my controller. Url is `http://localhost:8080/community/{communityNumber}/app`. Request result of

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/community/1/app?from=2018-11-14&till=2019-05-13&communityName=myCOm"
```

is:

```
{
  'from':'2018-11-14';
  'till':'2019-05-12';
  'communityNumber':'1';
  'communityName':'myCOm'
}
```

It seems works fine. Much more better to have in pojo data with required types by purposes. So I'd like to have fields `from` and `till` of `LocalDate` type. Using spring I'd like to have this solution almost *out the box*. But any spring or jackson date converters can't resolve my issue because of life cycle.

Spring validates types of pojo fields before injecting dates and I'm get type mismatch exception. I think the general reason is using special builder by spring that tries to find required parameters by name and it ignores annotations to be applied inside of pojo for the fields.

### Question is:

Is there any elegant solutions for building pojo by spring where some fields will be converted from `String` to `LocalDate` format by default?

### P.S.

Mandatory conditions are:

- request method is `GET`;
- required pojo is:

```
public class MyCriteria {
  private LocalDate from;
  private LocalDate till;
  private Long communityNumber;
  private String communityName;
}
```

- lets skip ideas with custom AOP implementations or with `getter`s where injected convert logic;
- there are neither body (request body is empty) nor json (all required data are path variables or path params).

### P.S.2.

- Controller example that can be used for experiments is:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.vl.example.rest.dtofromoaramsandpath.web.dto.MyCriteria;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("verify/criteria/mapping")
@Slf4j
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("community/{communityNumber}/dto")
    public MyCriteria loadDataByDto(MyCriteria criteria) {
        log.info("received criteria: {}", criteria);
        return criteria;
    }

    @GetMapping("community/{communityNumber}/default/params")
    public String loadDataByDefaultParameters(@PathVariable("communityNumber") String communityNumber,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) String from,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "till", required = false) String till,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "communityName", required = false) String communityName) {
        log.info("received data without converting:\n\tcommunityNumber => {}\n\tfrom => {}\n\ttill => {}\n\tcommunityName => {}",
                communityNumber, from, till, communityName);
        return new StringBuilder("{")
                .append("\n\tfrom:").append(from).append(";")
                .append("\n\tfrom:").append(from).append(";")
                .append("\n\ttill:").append(till).append(";")
                .append("\n\tcommunityName:").append(communityName)
                .append("\n}\n").toString();
    }

    @GetMapping("community/{communityNumber}/converted/params")
    public String loadUsingConvertedParameters(@PathVariable("communityNumber") String communityNumber,
                                             @RequestParam(value = "from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate from,
                                             @RequestParam("till") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate till,
                                             @RequestParam(value = "communityName", required = false) String communityName) {
        log.info("received data with LocalDate converting:\n\tcommunityNumber => {}\n\tfrom => {}\n\ttill => {}\n\tcommunityName => {}",
                communityNumber, from, till, communityName);
        return new StringBuilder("{")
                .append("\n\tfrom:").append(from).append(";")
                .append("\n\tfrom:").append(from).append(";")
                .append("\n\ttill:").append(till).append(";")
                .append("\n\tcommunityName:").append(communityName)
                .append("\n}\n").toString();
    }
}
```

- also [link on github project](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/elementary-java-lessons/tree/master/spring/criteria-dto) that contains module with required `controller` and `criteria` to make your understanding and experiments more useful.

Comment: Add your conotroller code

Comment: Controller code is very usual, but anyway, I've added it for you, see P.S.2 please and github link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on question is to use init binder to register type mapping inside of specified criteria. It is required to have `PropertyEditorSupport` implementation for specified purpose.

Short code example is:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                setValue(LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
            }
        });
    }
```

Full code example can be taken from [github](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/elementary-java-lessons/blob/master/spring/criteria-dto/src/main/java/org/vl/example/rest/dtofromoaramsandpath/web/dtofrompath/MyControllerLd.java):

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.vl.example.rest.dtofromoaramsandpath.web.dto.MyCriteriaLd;

import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("verify/criteria/mapping")
@Slf4j
public class MyControllerLd {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                setValue(LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
            }
        });
    }

    @GetMapping("community/{communityNumber}/dtold")
    public MyCriteriaLd loadDataByDto(MyCriteriaLd criteria) {
        log.info("received criteria: {}", criteria);
        return criteria;
    }
}
```

So model for this case can be next:

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
public class MyCriteriaLd {
    private LocalDate from;
    private LocalDate till;
    private Long communityNumber;
    private String communityName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you. I have similar situation and I used this approach to convert the data into specific requirement.

```
public class MyCriteria {
  public MyCriteria(LocalDate from, LocalDate till, Long communityNumber, String communityName){
   // assignement of variables
}
  private LocalDate from;
  private LocalDate till;
  private Long communityNumber;
  private String communityName;
}
```

SO whenever you create a object from JSON, it will create it according to the requirement.

When I implemented this, I used ObjectMapper class of "Jackson" to do this thing. Hope you are uisng the same.

Comment: I wrote, i do not have any `json` there.

Answer (score 2):

Use java.sql.Date inside the pojo class .like private Date from. I hope it will work for JSON convertion. When you are receiving date  JSON field from UI then always use Java.sql.Date for Jackson date convert.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need to add **jsr310** dependency.

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.10")
```

I hope this works fine for you.

Comment: I tried it also. It doesn't work in described conditions.